# Convert string data in to a valida struct to store as json data using golang

Tags: json, go

```
Sample data:
------------
mydata {
    timestamp: 1121245658497197000000
    content {
      origin: demoproj
      elem {
        name: projects
      }
      elem {
        name: project
        key {
           key: name
           value: default
         }
       }
       elem {
         name: abcd
       }
       elem {
         name: efgh
       }
       elem {
         name: interfaces
       }
       elem {
         name: interface
         key {
           key: name
           value: testdata
         }
       }
       elem {
         name: ijkl
       }
       elem {
         name: mnop
       }
     }
}
```

I am new to golang programming.

The problem here the data is not in a valid json structure, i read this data from a file and stored in a string.

I had tried to convert this into string array and with positions i am trying to read the string data and assigned to stuct objec.

Can any one please give some suggestions or a sample code to read this string data and convert that data in to a valid json structure using golang code.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one please give some suggestions or a sample code to read this string data and convert that data in to a valid json structure

The JSON is not valid for several reasons. The first is that the keys that contain letters have to be double quoted. And, at least when I edited your JSON code in Visual Studio Code, it told me that the JSON code cannot have duplicate keys. So I think that if you leave your JSON code like this, it could work:

```
{
    "mydata": {
        "timestamp": 1121245658497197000000,
        "content": {
         "origin": "demoproj",
         "elem": {
            "name": "projects"
         }
        }
    }
}
```